# Error trying to read an XML Document(C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, google-maps

I have the following XML that I am trying to "load" into an XmlDocument object:[Link to XML File](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Jamaica,%20NY%2011418&destination=Hunter%20College%20Park%20Avenue%20New%20York&mode=&alternatives=true&key=AIzaSyB8G9omVUu6a_OQCrRM-QItdwk-Hxq__mg)

I have the following method piece of code to load the XML document:

```
public XmlDocument getDirections()
    {
        XmlTextReader xmlReader;
        XmlDocument xmlResponse = new XmlDocument();
        StringBuilder xmlResponseString = new StringBuilder();
        xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(getRequestURL()); //getRequestURL gives the URL for XML doucument

        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                xmlResponseString.Append(xmlReader.ReadInnerXml());
            }
        }
        xmlResponse.LoadXml(xmlResponseString.ToString());
        return xmlResponse;
     }
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: There are multiple root elements. Line 3, position 3.
```

I figured this happens because the XML document have multiple `route` objects but I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Please post your XML content

Comment: This seems like a pretty convoluted way of parsing XML. What's wrong with `XmlDocument.Load(url)`? Or ideally, using LINQ to XML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the point of doing it that way? Use the built in functionality for getting Xml from a Url:

```
var str = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Jamaica,%20NY%2011418&destination=Hunter%20College%20Park%20Avenue%20New%20York&mode=&alternatives=true&key=AIzaSyB8G9omVUu6a_OQCrRM-QItdwk-Hxq__mg";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(str);

//or
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(str);
```

I would look into Linq to Xml (`XDocument`) over `XmlDocument`.  It's a lot easier to work with.

Comment: This method works...but I am curious as to why my original code does not work ?

Comment: perhaps someone could answer that if you were to post what your existing xml looks like.. did you even read the error message.. we can't answer that without seeing your xml do not post links edit your original question and post the xml in your edit

Comment: your method removes the root node, making the xml invalid, for one thing

Comment: As the saying very well puts it. "There's more than one way to skin a cat.".  Some ways are just easier than others.

Comment: links are not advisable when posting code.. who knows what's embedded in that link.. thank you..

Comment: @MethodMan Looks like you too sensitive to dangers of the internet...you are more than free to ignore this question...

Comment: `good luck` @JennaMaiz perhaps providing what others have requested may yield in you getting the answer that you are seeking

Answer (score 2):

The line where it says:

```
Additional information: There are multiple root elements. Line 3, position 3.
```

This is your clue.

Properly formatted XML will have 1 root element.

Ex.

```
<root>
   <child>
     <subchild>.....</subchild>
   </child>
</root>
```

See for a further explanation: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use following snippet to load xml.

```
public XmlDocument getDirections()
    {
        XmlTextReader xmlReader;
        XmlDocument xmlResponse = new XmlDocument();
        StringBuilder xmlResponseString = new StringBuilder();
        HttpWebRequest request =HttpWebRequest.Create(getRequestURL());

        using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    xmlResponse.Load(responseStream);
                }
            }
        }            
        xmlResponse.LoadXml(xmlResponseString.ToString());
        return xmlResponse;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar incident when trying to read an Xml using the XmlReader.

My code:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(filesContent)))
{
    while (reader.Read())     //<--- This is where the exception was caught
    {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

The exception caught:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in
>   System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: There are multiple root elements. Line X,
>   position Y.

*Note: The information regarding the location of the line and position which were provided in the exception were not the actual line or the position in the xml file content where my additional root was, making this a bit misleading.*

A properly formatted xml file should **contain only ONE root**. As such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<root1>
   <child1>
     <subchild1>.....</subchild1>
   </child1>
</root1>
```

In my case the exception was being thrown because **my xml file contained 2 roots**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root1>
   <child1>
     <subchild1>.....</subchild1>
   </child1>
</root1>
<root2>
   <child1>
     <subchild1>.....</subchild1>
     <subchild2>.....</subchild2>
   </child1>
   <child2>
     <subchild1>.....</subchild1>
   </child2>
</root2>
```

This could easily be fixed by adding some **'parentroot'** to the file, making the 2 roots nest under the new parent root as such

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<parnetroot>    
    <root1>
       <child>
         <subchild>.....</subchild>
       </child>
    </root1>
    <root2>
       <child1>
         <subchild1>.....</subchild1>
         <subchild2>.....</subchild2>
       </child1>
       <child2>
         <subchild1>.....</subchild1>
       </child2>
    </root2>
</parnetroot>
```